# Error coming out in some IE while uploading file

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Facing a strange situation here. following code is working fine everywhere even in IE but in some IE it is producing following error, just dont know why it is coming and how to resolve this. please help me out.

```
// controller side code
@RequestMapping(value = "upload", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
public @ResponseBody String upload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
@RequestPart("dataFile") MultipartFile file
){ if(file!=null){
//code to upload file and will return 1
        return "1";
    }
    return "0";//otherwise it will return 0
}
```

// code in javascript which submits iframe(which submits form) to controller

```
<html>

<script language="Javascript">
function fileUpload(form, action_url, div_id) {
    // Create the iframe...
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("id", "upload_iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("name", "upload_iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("border", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("style", "width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");

    // Add to document...
    form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
    window.frames['upload_iframe'].name = "upload_iframe";

    iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");

    // Add event...
    var eventHandler = function () {

            if (iframeId.detachEvent) iframeId.detachEvent("onload", eventHandler);
            else iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);

            // Message from server...
            if (iframeId.contentDocument) {
                content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
            } else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {
                content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
            } else if (iframeId.document) {
                content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
            }

            document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = content;

            // Del the iframe...
            setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)', 250);
        }

    if (iframeId.addEventListener) iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);
    if (iframeId.attachEvent) iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler);

    // Set properties of form...
    form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");
    form.setAttribute("action", action_url);
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    form.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data");

    // Submit the form...
    form.submit();

    document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = "Uploading...";
}
</script>

//html code 
<!-- index.php could be any script server-side for receive uploads. -->
<form>
<input type="file" name="dataFile" id="dataFile" /></br>
<input type="button" value="upload"
        onClick="fileUpload(this.form,'upload','uploadShow'); return false;" >
<div id="uploadShow"></div>
</form>

</html>
```

Following is the error which i am getting in some IE browser.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
                Windows                                                : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
                Common Language Runtime               : 4.0.30319.1022
                System.Deployment.dll                         : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
                clr.dll                                      : 4.0.30319.1022 (RTMGDR.030319-1000)
                dfdll.dll                                   : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
                dfshim.dll                                               : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
                Deployment url                                      : http://URL(cant show)

ERROR SUMMARY
                Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
                * Activation of http://URL(cant show) resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
                                + Downloading http://URL(cant show) did not succeed.
                                + The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
                No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
                There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
                * [30/04/2014 09:32:49] : Activation of http://URL(cant show) has started.

ERROR DETAILS
                Following errors were detected during this operation.
                * [30/04/2014 09:32:50] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
                                - Downloading http://URL(cant show) did not succeed.
                                - Source: System.Deployment
                                - Stack trace:
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
                                --- Inner Exception ---
                                System.Net.WebException
                                - The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
                                - Source: System
                                - Stack trace:
                                                at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
                No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: Try to add all the properties directly on form definition, for example: <form target="upload_iframe" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding="multipart/form-data> I'm not sure but maybe some older IE version can't understand form properties set via javascript.

Comment: your reason has worth !Thanks, i'll try and let you know.

Comment: Some version of IE have *major* issues with `setAttribute.`  In almost all cases, property access should be used instead.

Comment: Sorry guys problem is not that...tried but result is same. here file is getting uploaded which means error is coming while we are getting the response which is string, only at that time error is comming.